# Can you embed Flash (SWF) in Eclipse-RCP apps

Tags: flash, eclipse-rcp

I have no background in Eclipse-RCP. My understanding is that a eclipse-rcp app is a rich client technology similar to Adobe Air.

Is it possible to embed a swf flash movie in a panel inside a eclipse-rcp app? Can the flash talk via ExternalInterface to the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[embed flash via browser component](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg42142.html)
[swt / java and flash communication](http://osflash.org/pipermail/osflash_osflash.org/2005-October/004506.html)

I am assuming flash and swf is the same (being a long time since I did any director stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can find a reasonable tutorial at http://rcpquickstart.com/2009/03/03/video-and-eclipse/. Unfortunately it seems to have some issues with codecs, but hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that looks like Flash Video (.flv) not a .swf. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of a more direct option, you could embed the SWT browser widget with an html document that embeds your swf. Not the cleanest solution, but if you know there is a flash-enabled browser on your target platform, this will work.