# Embedding a Flash UI in a Java application

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash

What's out there that lets you do this?  Are there any OSS projects or maybe something a little more popular than this: http://www.jpackages.com/jflashplayer/ ?  This does exactly what I'm suggesting (i.e. cuts out the need for Swing UI for the most part) but for a number of reasons I'd be interested in any better alternatives. Are there any? Any alternatives would need to support the Flex SDK.

Comment: This is for a non-browser dependent application that has nothing to do with the Internet. It also can use Swing at the top level as a container (jflashplayer does), as long as you can use Flash components for the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SWT GUI toolkit, which has an embedded browser. You can even deploy you own webkit with it, and let flash run in this browser, so you are platform independent, and don't rely on native browsers.

It will however be a large deployment, because of the browsers size.

EDIT: You can also emed the Flash ActiveX control directly in an SWT composite (Composite is the JPanel of SWT)

Comment: See comment above, sorry. This is for a non-browser dependent application. For a browser app I just use plain Flash/Flex, cross platform and no reliance on native browsers.

Comment: Oh I think I may have misread, still, a Flash solution to take advantage of my Flex experience rather than having to learn a whole new toolkit would be ideal.

Comment: Another possibility is still to use SWT, and embed the Flash ActiveX Control. We already were able to embed Word and OpenOffice apps directly in our Java Windows (still using SWT here), because SWT is a native toolkit.

Comment: Ooh, that's an interesting idea. In a situation like that how would (could?) the Flash control communicate with the Java "container" it's embedded in? I had no idea such a thing was possible w/SWT.

Comment: You communicate by calling the COM methods by name. SWT contains an OLE bridge for that. http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2003/11/swt-flash.cfm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660887/can-you-embed-flash-swf-in-eclipse-rcp-apps

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX 2 has a web control. I can't remember if the beta can do flash yet or if still upcoming. But if it doesn't support flash yet then it probably will soon, they release updates every 2 or so weeks to test.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the JFlashPlayer from DJ Native Swing: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns

It is essentially the SWT Browser, but with all sorts of integration headaches solved, and proper API.