# Embed Adobe Flash player into Java based desktop application

Tags: java, flash, online-game

How can I embed a adobe flash player inside a java based desktop application? Can I be able to load and run an on-line flash game in it?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901363/embedding-a-flash-ui-in-a-java-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX 2 has a web control. I can't remember if the beta can do flash yet or if still upcoming. But if it doesn't support flash yet then it probably will soon, they release updates every 2 or so weeks to test.